# deleting set of data in json

Tags: python, json

Lets say I have the json file

```
{
    "emp_details": [
        {
            "emp_name": "Nikhil",
            "email": "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "job_profile": "Full Time"
        },
        {
            "emp_name": "John",
            "email": "John@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "job_profile": "Part Time"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to delete a set of data unique to a person, e.g all of Johns data, and for it also to be updated in the file.

Here's what I tried:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
  json_data = json.load(file)
  for item in json_data:
    if item['emp_name'] in ["Nikhil"]:
      del item
```

But nothing is deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    for  i, item in enumerate(json_data['emp_details']): # get index of nodes with enumerate
        if item['emp_name'] in ["Nikhil"]:
            del json_data['emp_details'][i] # and delete node meeting the condition
```

Output:

```
{'emp_details': 
    [{'emp_name': 'John',
      'email': 'John@geeksforgeeks.org',
      'job_profile': 'Part Time'}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just filter out the one you dont want to have

```
data = {
    "emp_details": [
        {
            "emp_name": "Nikhil",
            "email": "nikhil@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "job_profile": "Full Time"
        },
        {
            "emp_name": "John",
            "email": "John@geeksforgeeks.org",
            "job_profile": "Part Time"
        }
    ]
}

fitered_data = {"emp_details": [e for e in data["emp_details"] if e["emp_name"] != "Nikhil"]}
print(fitered_data)
```

output

```
{'emp_details': [{'emp_name': 'John', 'email': 'John@geeksforgeeks.org', 'job_profile': 'Part Time'}]}
```

Comment: thanks that solves half of it, but i want to delete all the data for that person

Comment: as you can see, everything that is related to Nikhil is removed. Isnt it?

Comment: yes but you are printing, i want to actually delete that specific data.

Comment: cleaned data is `filtered_data` (what you want), they just print it to show the result

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this method to open the json file:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
  json_data = json.load(file)
  for item in json_data:
    if item['emp_name'] in ["Nikhil"]:
      del item['emp_name']
```

Comment: see my edit, i was meant to say i wanted to delete all data for that person